# Correct use of UMD - Ramjet JS

Tags: javascript, umd

Complete Code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/york_5/jqondo22/8/)

I'm trying to learn UMD, I took a day trying to run this [Ramjet JS](https://github.com/Rich-Harris/ramjet). I don't understand this error that occurs here:

```
(function (global, factory) {
                typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
                typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
                (global.ramjet = factory());
    }(this, function () { 'use strict';
...
```

It's just at the beginning, it must be a very foolish mistake.

Specifically in the line:

- (global.ramjet = factory());

Google chrome console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'ramjet' of undefined
>
> (anonymous function) @ ramjet.umd.js:4
>
> (anonymous function) @ ramjet.umd.js:1

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that Babel, compiled bad UMD ramjet.

The solution has been to concatenate the end uncompiled code.